# Spring 5 exception handling - ResponseStatusException model

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was reading the article - https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring
which says

> Spring 5 introduced the ResponseStatusException class.
>
> We can create an instance of it providing an HttpStatus and optionally
> a reason and a cause:

I started implementing it , and the code is

1. custom exception

```java
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Actor Not Found")
public class ActorNotFoundException extends Exception {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public ActorNotFoundException(String errorMessage) {
      super(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

2. method in service

```java
public String updateActor(int index, String actorName) throws ActorNotFoundException {
  if (index >= actors.size()) {
    throw new ActorNotFoundException("Actor Not Found in Repsoitory");
  }
  actors.set(index, actorName);
  return actorName;
}
```

3. controller

```java
@GetMapping("/actor/{id}")
public String getActorName(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
  try {
    return actorService.getActor(id);
  } catch (ActorNotFoundException ex) {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Actor Not Found", ex); //agreed it could be optional, but we may need original exception
  }
}
```

repo:
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-5/src/main/java/com/baeldung/exception

Question:

why ResponseStatusException in controller again has to specify reason - "Actor Not Found" ?, as the service already said - ""Actor Not Found in Repsoitory"

What is the proper way to adapt to ResponseStatusException model?

Comment: Why not `throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getMessage(), ex);` !? ;)

Comment: You can throw ResponseStatusException directly, or you can extend it. Spring has rebased their own exceptions like this too, e.g. MethodNotAllowedException now extends ResponseStatusException.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mistake. Ideally the service shouldn't use any HTTP code, so I would remove the annotation in `ActorNotFoundException`. Everything else seems fine, the exception is caught in the controller and `ResponseStatusException` is thrown which is good, because it's a proper layer to put HTTP stuff.